# Specifying a jQuery mobile main page

Tags: java, android, apache, jquery-mobile, cordova

Given a jQuery Mobile app with several pages

```
Home.html > Profile.html > Registration.html > ...
```

How do i set up my app so `Home` is the page that loads first and is presented to the user when they launch the app on their mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what are you doing.

If you are creating a basic mobile web page that this depends on your web server. If you are working with Apache web server you would change **httpd.conf** and replace this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

with this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html main.html
```

Or if you don't have access to your web server you would create a **.htaccess** in your project directory and do same thing as above. Read more about it **[here](http://bignosebird.com/apache/a2.shtml)**.

On the other hand, if you are working with Phonegap then all you need to do is change location Phonegap looks for app initialization.

This is Android example:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/main.html");
```

Read more about it **[here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html)**.

But you should stick to standards and rename main file to **index.html**

iOS is little bit different, unlike Android, you need to change some configurations thus forcing iOS to load different file then index.html.

In Classes folder open AppDelegate.m and change this:

```
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
```

to this:

```
self.viewController.startPage = @"main.html";
```

Comment: Am working with Google App Engine, and PyCharm. All the files for my project (client and server) are in the same directory.

Comment: Your file structure doesn't matter, everything depends your app wrapper, be it web server or Phonegap. You can't configure jQuery Mobile to determine initial HTML file, it is always a web server of Phonegap wrapper.

Comment: Okay.Could you please provide a link to where i can read more on this in your answer?

Comment: About what I gave you everything you need to know?